# css , asp.net : fill a division with panels

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a division filling it with panels. But inside the division the panels are sorted up to down. I want to have them next to each other.

e.g:

panel_1   panel_2    panel_3

panel_4   panel_5    panel_6

panel_7   panel_8    panel_9

How can I succeed this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this your the style of your panels:

```
float: left;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like

`<div style="width:300px">
    <div style="float:left; width:100px; background:pink;"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100px; background:orange;"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100px; background:green;"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100px; background:blue;"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100px; background:white;"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100px; background:black;"></div>
</div>`

The colours are there for testing and i would make it into a class but you get the point.

Comment: Xavier answer helps already, thanks for the example. i'm adding panel's dynamically, already with a css-class it goes well =) i've solved my problem. thank you all.